# Split one column to two by space of mixed object type data

Tags: python, split

I would like to split this column into 2 by the space between

`V_FP_PORTF_SWAP_RAW` and `1ST_T3_01 01/02`

I have tried using this code:

```
new=cdms['ETL_NAME'].str.split(" ", n=1,expand=True)
```

However, it returns

```
TypeError: Cannot use .str.split with values of inferred dtype 'bytes'
```

How can I split this kind of object type data?

[image]

Comment: Seems the object you are trying to modify is a `bytes` object. Convert it to a string by either doing `str(obj)` or `obj.decode('utf-8')` I recommend decoding it using the proper encoding.

Comment: the type `bytes` means your string is still encoded and not Unicode, convert it to Unicode string

Comment: @PrestonHager Got it! Thank you!!!

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you for your help on editing my post and providing solution as well!